# libgdx admob adSize undefined

Tags: libgdx, admob

I am trying to implement ads in my libgdx game. I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

The problem is with these lines.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); 
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I get the error, "The constructor AdView(MainActivity, AdSize, String) is undefined". 
Why? I am importing "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you followed seems outdated, It is based on AdMob 4.0.4, whereas I guess you are using the latest version (4.1).

Fortunately there is a [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration). You have to update your code like this :

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxx");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```

Hope this helps.